# Number of character cells used by string

Tags: c, linux, string, utf-8

I have a program that outputs a textual table using UTF-8 strings, and I need to measure the number of monospaced character cells used by a string so I can align it properly. If possible, I'd like to do this with standard functions.

Comment: > UTF-8 string is a null-terminated string

It depends whether you allow or expect U+0000 code point inside.

Comment: @adobriyan – U+0000 is the null character, so it terminates a null-terminated Unicode string, which in UTF-8 happens to also be a null-terminated char string – right? :)

Comment: U+0000 by definition terminates "null-terminated Unicode string". :-)

But, but.

If you look at strings C way, U+0000 can never appear in it.

If you look at strings as one-dimensional array with element type being character (Unicode), U+0000 doesn't terminate such string.

Comment: @aaz: a unicode string should be able to represent all valid unicode character sequences, ie you can't use U+0000 as sentinel value; that's where 'modified UTF8' comes in: it encodes U+0000 as the two-byte sequence 0xC0,0x80, thus freeing the single byte 0x00 for use as string terminator...

Comment: @adobriyan  that in no way makes it different from an ASCII string. By convention C strings are terminated with a 0x00 byte, UTF8 strings are the same. here 0x00 represents U+0000 because ASCII and unicode share the same first 0x80 code points.

Comment: In UTF-8, every code point from 0-127 is stored in a single byte. Code points 128 and above are stored using 2, 3, in fact, up to 6 bytes (!)

Comment: Aligning monospace text by counting unicode characters is wrong; you need the width counted from each character to properly align them. For example a single Chinese character in UTF-8 takes 3 bytes on coding, and 2 character-width on monospace display.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From [UTF-8 and Unicode FAQ for Unix/Linux](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html#mod):

> The number of characters can be counted in C in a portable way using `mbstowcs(NULL,s,0)`. This works for UTF-8 like for any other supported encoding, as long as the appropriate locale has been selected. A hard-wired technique to count the number of characters in a UTF-8 string is to count all bytes except those in the range 0x80 – 0xBF, because these are just continuation bytes and not characters of their own. However, the need to count characters arises surprisingly rarely in applications.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit more lightweight than the ICU libraries! +1

Comment: keep in mind that counting codepoints will give the wrong answer if combining characters are involved; even normalizint the input won't help as there are graphemes which do not map to single codepoints...

Comment: In the context of alignment (as per the question), the same document says that character counts are not sufficient: "neither a byte nor a character count will predict the display width, because ideographic characters (Chinese, Japanese, Korean) will occupy two column positions, whereas control and combining characters occupy none. To determine the width of a string on the terminal screen, it is necessary to decode the UTF-8 sequence and then use the wcwidth function to test the display width of each character, or wcswidth to measure the entire string."

Answer (score 20):

You may or may not have a UTF-8 compatible strlen(3) function available.  However, there are s[ome simple C functions readily available](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html) that do the job quickly.

The efficient C solutions examine the start of the character to skip continuation bytes.  The simple code (referenced from the link above) is

```
int my_strlen_utf8_c(char *s) {
   int i = 0, j = 0;
   while (s[i]) {
     if ((s[i] & 0xc0) != 0x80) j++;
     i++;
   }
   return j;
}
```

The faster version uses the same technique, but prefetches data and does multi-byte compares, resulting is a substantial speedup.  The code is longer and more complex, however.

Comment: I think works better like this `size_t my_strlen_utf8_c(const char *s)`

Answer (score 20):

I'm shocked that no one mentioned this, so here it goes for the record:

If you want to align text in a terminal, you need to use the POSIX functions [`wcwidth`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcwidth) and [`wcswidth`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/wcswidth). Here's correct program to find the on-screen length of a string.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int measure(char *string) {
    // allocate enough memory to hold the wide string
    size_t needed = mbstowcs(NULL, string, 0) + 1;
    wchar_t *wcstring = malloc(needed * sizeof *wcstring);
    if (!wcstring) return -1;

    // change encodings
    if (mbstowcs(wcstring, string, needed) == (size_t)-1) return -2;

    // measure width
    int width = wcswidth(wcstring, needed);

    free(wcstring);
    return width;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("%s: %d\n", argv[i], measure(argv[i]));
    }
}
```

Here's an example of it running:

```
$ ./measure hello 莊子 cＡb
hello: 5
莊子: 4
cＡb: 4
```

Note how the two characters "莊子" and the three characters "cＡb" (note the double-width Ａ) are both 4 columns wide.

As utf8everywhere.org [puts it](http://utf8everywhere.org/#myth.strlen),

> The size of the string as it appears on the screen is unrelated to the
>   number of code points in the string. One has to communicate with the
>   rendering engine for this. Code points do not occupy one column even
>   in monospace fonts and terminals. POSIX takes this into account.

Windows does not have any built-in `wcwidth` function for console output; if you want to support multi-column characters in the Windows console <strike>you need to find a portable implementation of `wcwidth`</strike> give up because the Windows console doesn’t support Unicode without crazy hacks.

Comment: +1 for the only correct answer in here... Did you know about wcwidth beforehand or you looked at the hidden comment in the manifesto? hehe :D
Btw, Windows console still works in UCS-2 and I guess does not even support double-width characters.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Glad to see someone saw this!

Answer (score 4):

If you are able to use 3rd party libraries, have a look at the [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/) from IBM.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh The Unicode standard is also heavy, and counting characters is one of the trickier parts.

Answer (score 3):

The following code takes ill-formed byte sequences into consideration. the example of string data comes from "["Table 3-8. Use of U+FFFD in UTF-8 Conversion"](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.3.0/ch03.pdf)" in the Unicode Standard 6.3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define is_trail(c) (c > 0x7F && c < 0xC0)
#define SUCCESS 1
#define FAILURE -1

int utf8_get_next_char(const unsigned char*, size_t, size_t*, int*, unsigned int*);
int utf8_length(unsigned char*, size_t);
void utf8_print_each_char(unsigned char*, size_t);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char *str;
    str = (unsigned char *) "\x61\xF1\x80\x80\xE1\x80\xC2\x62\x80\x63\x80\xBF\x64";
    size_t str_size = strlen((const char*) str);

    puts(10 == utf8_length(str, str_size) ? "true" : "false");
    utf8_print_each_char(str, str_size);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int utf8_length(unsigned char *str, size_t str_size)
{
    int length = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t next_pos = 0;
    int is_valid = 0;
    unsigned int code_point = 0;

    while (
        utf8_get_next_char(str, str_size, &next_pos, &is_valid, &code_point) == SUCCESS
    ) {
        ++length;
    }

    return length;
}

void utf8_print_each_char(unsigned char *str, size_t str_size)
{
    int length = 0;
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t next_pos = 0;
    int is_valid = 0;
    unsigned int code_point = 0;

    while (
        utf8_get_next_char(str, str_size, &next_pos, &is_valid, &code_point) == SUCCESS
    ) {
        if (is_valid == true) {
            printf("%.*s\n", (int) next_pos - (int) pos, str + pos);
        } else {
            puts("\xEF\xBF\xBD");
        }

        pos = next_pos;
    }
}

int utf8_get_next_char(const unsigned char *str, size_t str_size, size_t *cursor, int *is_valid, unsigned int *code_point)
{
    size_t pos = *cursor;
    size_t rest_size = str_size - pos;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char min;
    unsigned char max;

    *code_point = 0;
    *is_valid = SUCCESS;

    if (*cursor >= str_size) {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    c = str[pos];

    if (rest_size < 1) {
        *is_valid = false;
        pos += 1;
    } else if (c < 0x80) {
        *code_point = str[pos];
        *is_valid = true;
        pos += 1;
    } else if (c < 0xC2) {
        *is_valid = false;
        pos += 1;
    } else if (c < 0xE0) {

        if (rest_size < 2 || !is_trail(str[pos + 1])) {
            *is_valid = false;
            pos += 1;
        } else {
            *code_point = ((str[pos] & 0x1F) << 6) | (str[pos + 1] & 0x3F);
            *is_valid = true;
            pos += 2;
        }

    } else if (c < 0xF0) {

        min = (c == 0xE0) ? 0xA0 : 0x80;
        max = (c == 0xED) ? 0x9F : 0xBF;

        if (rest_size < 2 || str[pos + 1] < min || max < str[pos + 1]) {
            *is_valid = false;
            pos += 1;         
        } else if (rest_size < 3 || !is_trail(str[pos + 2])) {
            *is_valid = false;
            pos += 2;
        } else {
            *code_point = ((str[pos]     & 0x1F) << 12) 
                       | ((str[pos + 1] & 0x3F) <<  6) 
                       |  (str[pos + 2] & 0x3F);
            *is_valid = true;
            pos += 3;
        }

    } else if (c < 0xF5) {

        min = (c == 0xF0) ? 0x90 : 0x80;
        max = (c == 0xF4) ? 0x8F : 0xBF;

        if (rest_size < 2 || str[pos + 1] < min || max < str[pos + 1]) {
            *is_valid = false;
            pos += 1;
        } else if (rest_size < 3 || !is_trail(str[pos + 2])) {
            *is_valid = false;
            pos += 2;
        } else if (rest_size < 4 || !is_trail(str[pos + 3])) {
            *is_valid = false;
            pos += 3;
        } else {
            *code_point = ((str[pos]     &  0x7) << 18)
                       | ((str[pos + 1] & 0x3F) << 12)
                       | ((str[pos + 2] & 0x3F) << 6)
                       |  (str[pos + 3] & 0x3F);
            *is_valid = true;
            pos += 4;
        }

    } else {
        *is_valid = false;
        pos += 1;
    }

    *cursor = pos;

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

When I write code for UTF-8, I see "Table 3-7. Well-Formed UTF-8 Byte Sequences" in the Unicode Standard 6.3.

```
       Code Points    First Byte Second Byte Third Byte Fourth Byte
  U+0000 -   U+007F   00 - 7F
  U+0080 -   U+07FF   C2 - DF    80 - BF
  U+0800 -   U+0FFF   E0         A0 - BF     80 - BF
  U+1000 -   U+CFFF   E1 - EC    80 - BF     80 - BF
  U+D000 -   U+D7FF   ED         80 - 9F     80 - BF
  U+E000 -   U+FFFF   EE - EF    80 - BF     80 - BF
 U+10000 -  U+3FFFF   F0         90 - BF     80 - BF    80 - BF
 U+40000 -  U+FFFFF   F1 - F3    80 - BF     80 - BF    80 - BF
U+100000 - U+10FFFF   F4         80 - 8F     80 - BF    80 - BF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [glib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/) which makes your life much easier when dealing with UTF-8.