# Standard C strings in android NDK

Tags: android, c, string, encoding, android-ndk

Does anyone know what is the default c-string encoding in android NDK?

OS X and iOS i.e. use UTF-8 strings, windows uses ANSI strings. What about android?

Answer (score 1):

NDK is kind of encoding-ignorant. Its C strings cannot be directly displayed. But if you use JNI to pass these strings to the Java application layer, you should prepare them as [Modified UTF-8](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#UTF_8_and_UTF_16_strings).

Comment: Actually I mean a little bit different thing. What encodings do functions like strcpy, strlen, etc. accept? It depends on platform. As I mentioned in question "OS X and iOS i.e. use UTF-8 strings, windows uses ANSI strings", but what about android?

Comment: C strings in general are encoding-indifferent, i.e. they are defined as data structures that contain char (8-bit signed or unsigned) array with `'\0'` on the tail. In some systems, there may be API that can use these strings for display, but on Android,  this can only be dine through JNI.

Comment: Well, one special case is with functions `open()` and `fopen()`. They communicate with the underlying Linux file system,  and thus use non-modified UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I know exactly what UTF-8 is. This is not my question. Let's try to clarify again. On Windows strlen can NOT work with UTF-8 and works with ANSI only. On OS X strlen works with UTF-8 strings. What about strlen on android?

Comment: No, `strlen()` is locale and encoding independent. It always returns the number of bytes that are enough to hold the given string string, excluding the terminating zero. There exist Microsoft extensions e.g. `strlen_l()`, but to find that the actual number of characters in string `"\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0"` is actually 4 characters you need `mbcslen()` or `mbstowcs(NULL,s,0)`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117393/utf-8-strings-length-in-linux-c for discussion.