# Getting the string length on UTF-8 in C?

Tags: c, string, utf-8

Can this be done using a method similar to this one:

As long as the current element of the string the user input via scanf is not \0, add one to the "length" int and then print out the length.

I would be very grateful if anybody could guide me through the least complex way possible as I am a beginner.

Thank you very much, have a good one!

Comment: `mblen()/mbrlen()` to find the length of each character, then write your own function that iterates over the string until the terminator, adding the lengths of the characters?

Comment: Your method will return the number of bytes, just as for any zero-terminated string. Sounds like you want the number of characters instead, though. Either way, this is a FAQ, and it should be easy to find a duplicate which satisfies your requirements (as well as explains the complications you are glossing over).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 string's length in linux, C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117393/utf-8-strings-length-in-linux-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What do you mean by *string length*?

The UTF-8 encoding is very well designed and compatible with the definition of C strings, UTF-8 strings are just null terminated arrays of bytes, like ASCII strings.

The number of bytes is easily obtained with `strlen(s)`. If for some reason you cannot use `strlen`, it is easy to emulate and the algorithm is exactly what you propose in the question:

```
size_t string_lengh(const char *s) {
    size_t length = 0;
    while (*s++ != '\0')
        length++;
    return length;
}
```

The number of code points encoded in UTF-8 can be computed by counting the number of single byte chars (range 1 to 127) and the number of leading bytes (range 0xC0 to 0xFF), ignoring continuation bytes (range 0x80 to 0xBF) and stopping at `'\0'`.

Here is a simple function to do this:

```
size_t count_utf8_code_points(const char *s) {
    size_t count = 0;
    while (*s) {
        count += (*s++ & 0xC0) != 0x80;
    }
    return count;
}
```

This function assumes that the contents of the array pointed to by `s` is properly encoded.

Also note that this will compute the number of code points, not the number of characters displayed, as some of these may be encoded using multiple combining code points, such as `<LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A>` followed by `<COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT>`.

Comment: Correct, except your range should be 0xC2 to 0xF4, else there are invalid UTF-8 sequences since there are no code points beyond U+10FFFF (F4 8F BF BF), and 0xC1 and 0xC0 would both denote an [overlong byte sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings), which is invalid.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune: As stated above, the function does not attempt to check proper encoding.  If the string is properly encoded, the function will return the correct number of code points.  If it is not, your proposed changes would fall short of providing complete string validation: counting continuation bytes, checking for overlong sequences and invalid code points would require a lot more code.

Comment: I suppose if you are able to trust the input data, then the fact is that your code is good enough without slowing down anything due to validation.

Comment: I was thinking about the number of characters in the string minus the \0. And is it doable without the strlen function?

Comment: @Daeto: if you mean the number of `char`, just use `strlen(s)`.  If you mean something else by *character*, be more concise.

Comment: I mean exactly this, how long the input word is for example. But lets say I cannot use strlen, how would I go about it then?

Comment: Why could you not use `strlen`?  `strlen` is quite trivial to re-implement:  `size_t strlen(const char *s) { const char *a = s; while (*s) s++; return s - a; }`

Comment: I was trying to come up with an algorithm manually that would count the length of the string. And I did and it works properly now for me. So problem resolved : ) Thanks everyone for replies though, it seems that there was some kind of a bug in my simple program that was giving me the number 102 for every string and I thought it might have been because i switched to UTF-8 recently. But now it works as it should : ) Sorry if the question sounded unclear.