# strlen() not working well with special characters

Tags: c++, string, char

When trying to determine the length of a low-level character string with the strlen function of  I have noticed that it does not work properly when the string contains Spanish characters that do not exist in English, such as the exclamation opening symbol !, accents or the letter ñ. All these elements are counted as two characters, a situation that is not fixed with Locale.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char * s1 = "Hola!";
    const char * s2 = "¡Hola!";
    std::cout << s1 << " has " << strlen(s1) << " elements, but " <<  s2
              << " has " << strlen(s2) << " intead of 6" << std::endl;
}
```

This is a work for the university on low-level strings, so it is not possible to use libraries as strings.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32936928/10411602

Comment: I'm assuming your platform is using UTF-8 encoding.  The `strlen` function measures the number of bytes used in the backing store, not including the terminating '\0'.  Strings like `¡Hola!` use multiple bytes (UTF-8 encoding units) for the non-ASCII range Unicode characters.

Comment: @Eljay applies to other UTF encondings as well.

Comment: You could have stopped typing after 'strlen not working well'.

Comment: @user1810087 • `strlen` has more surprising (and disappointing) behavior for UTF-16 and UTF-32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strlen` gives you the number of non-zero `char` objects in the buffer pointed to by its argument, up to the first zero `char`. Your system is apparently using a character encoding (most likely UTF-8) where these problematic characters take up more than one byte (that is, more than one `char` object).

How to solve this depends on what you're trying to do. For certain operations (such as determining the size of a buffer needed to store the string), the result from `strlen` is 100% correct, as it's exactly what you need. For most other purposes, welcome to the vast world of character/byte/code-point/whatever nuances. You might want to read up on text encodings, Unicode etc. http://utf8everywhere.org/ might be a good site to start.

You've mentioned this is a university assignment: based on what the teaching goal is, you might need to implement some form of UTF en/de-coding, or just steer clear of non-ASCII characters.

Comment: You're right, I use strlen to calculate the buffer size I need to store the string, but the class must have a method to return the number of characters it contains from the user's point of view. Thank you so much, I'm reading it