# UTF-8, sprintf, strlen, etc

Tags: c++, utf-8

I try to understand how to handle basic UTF-8 operations in C++.

Let's say we have this scenario: User inputs a name, it's limited to 10 letters (symbols in user's language, not bytes), it's being stored.

It can be done this way in ASCII.

```
// ASCII 
char * input; // user's input
char buf[11] // 10 letters + zero
snprintf(buf,11,"%s",input); buf[10]=0;
int len= strlen(buf); // return 10 (correct)
```

Now, how to do it in UTF-8? Let's assume it's up to 4 bytes charset (like Chinese).

```
// UTF-8
char * input; // user's input
char buf[41] // 10 letters * 4 bytes + zero
snprintf(buf,41,"%s",input); //?? makes no sense, it limits by number of bytes not letters
int len= strlen(buf); // return number of bytes not letters (incorrect)
```

Can it be done with standard sprintf/strlen? Are there any replacements of those function to use with UTF-8 (in PHP there was mb_ prefix of such functions IIRC)? If not, do I need to write those myself? Or maybe do I need to approach it another way?

Note: I would prefer to avoid wide characters solution...

*EDIT: Let's limit it to Basic Multilingual Plane only.*

Comment: Can you use boost::locale? You can do it with `boost::locale::boundary::character` (I think it's available also in [ICU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Components_for_Unicode) but it uses `wchar_t`). If boost (or another library) isn't an option then AFAIK you have to roll your own...

Comment: I guess you'll need to use [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: You can count the number of characters: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117481/412080

Comment: Are you saying that I can't enter  as my username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would prefer to avoid wide characters solution...

Wide characters are just not enough, because if you need 4 bytes for a single glyph, then that glyph is likely to be outside the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), and it will not be represented by a single  16 bits `wchar_t` character (assuming wchar_t is 16 bits wide which is just the common size).

You will have to use a true unicode library to convert the input to a *list* of unicode characters in their Normal Form C (canonical composition) or the compatibility equivalent (NFKC)(*) depending on whether for example you want to count one or two characters for the ligature `ﬀ` (U+FB00). AFAIK, you best bet should be [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

---

(*) Unicode allows multiple representation for the same glyph, notably the normal composed form (NFC) and normal decomposed form (NFD). For example the french `é` character can be represented in NFC as U+00E9 or LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE or as U+0065 U+0301 or LATIN SMALL LETTER E followed with COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT (also displayed as `é`).

References and other examples on [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence)

Comment: I see... OK, let's limit the question to Basic Multilingual Plane, since that's what I would need for any reasonable practical purpose.

Comment: Even in the BMP, this utf-8 string: `const char *dec_e_accute = "e\xcc\x81";`, will count for 2 `wchar_t` (0x65 and 0x301) while it is the NFD form of `é`. You should be aware of that even if you can choose not to handle it.

Comment: I see... Is this character you mentioned "important"? Are there more characeters like that? Overall, do you think, for standard uses, is supporting outside of 2 bytes important?

Comment: If you only intend to support european character sets, the BMP is enough. Decomposition can be used for most non english languages. French uses éèàçù, Spanish also uses accents and ñ, german uses ö, ü and eszett (ß) can be decomposed as ss, not speaking of nordic languages

Comment: I would like to have also Chinese and Japanese.

Comment: @Chris: I'm not used to CJK characters, so I do not know whether the BMP is enough for chinese...

Comment: For UTF-16 there are _many_ CJK character not included in BMP (I'm not sure for Simplified Chinese but surely for Traditional Chinese - and then Japanese Kanji characters). Some Korean characters are even encoded with two Unicode code-points (then you will need more than one `wchar_t` even with a 4 bytes UTF-32)

Answer (score 1):

`strlen` only counts the *bytes* in the input string, until the terminating `NUL`.

On the other hand, you seem interested in the *glyph* count (what you called *"symbols in user's language"*).

The process is complicated by UTF-8 being a *variable length* encoding (as is, in a kind of lesser extent, also UTF-16), so code points can be encoded using one up to four bytes. And there are also [Unicode combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) to consider.

To my knowledge, there's nothing like that in the standard C++ library. However, you may have better luck using third party libraries like [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: You can roll your own quite simply with `std::mblen`, if it's for the platform's native multibyte encoding, without all the generality of ICU.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of this function. I tried [that sample code](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mblen) with VS2015 in a  Windows console application, and it doesn't work (prints `"... only 10 characters"` instead of `4`).

Comment: @TobySpeight : But you can't avoid ICU if you want to allow both "LATIN SMALL LETTER A" + "COMBINING DIAERESIS" and "LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS" as a single "character".  Is this also an issue for some chinese characters?

Comment: @MartinBonner, quite right - I possibly misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: In my answer I pointed out the problem of Unicode combining characters, and Martin Bonner stated that again in the comments here. Does [your linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117481/1629821) take into account this point?

Comment: Nope, it does not.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Thanks for the clarification. This may be an interesting point to consider for the C++ standard library designers.

Comment: @Mr.C64 : In Python you have one module for normal conversions (codecs), and a different module for specific Unicode handling (unicodedata). Conversions are now rather correctly handled by the standard C++ library (even if not really programmer friendly), but unicode handling is just not present at all and requires usage of a third party library like ICU.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to count utf-8 chars by yourself - you can use temporary conversion to widechar to cut your input string. You do not need to store the intermediate values

```
#include <iostream>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>
#include <locale>

std::string cutString(const std::string& in, size_t len)
{
    std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> cvt;
    auto wstring = cvt.from_bytes(in);
    if(len < wstring.length())
    {
        wstring = wstring.substr(0,len);
        return cvt.to_bytes(wstring);
    }    
    return in;
}
int main(){
    std::string test = "你好世界這是演示樣本";

    std::string res = cutString(test,5);
    std::cout << test << '\n' << res << '\n';

    return 0;
}

/****************
Output 
$ ./test
你好世界這是演示樣本
你好世界這
*/
```

Comment: But wstring uses wchar_t, which is 2 bytes in Windows, correct? So that's up to 65,536 symbols. UNICODE contains 136,000 symbols total (version 10.0). Therefore wstring won't be able to store it? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Chris : Not a lot.  On Windows, wchar_t is UTF-16, which is *still* a variable length encoding.  In addition, users are quite likely to think of two Unicode code points as a single character (for example, "LATIN SMALL LETTER A" + "COMBINING DIAERESIS" - although there is a combined character for that particular combination).  This is a hard problem; Unicode may be awful, but it is still miles better than what we had before.

Comment: If you are bothered by wchar_t being char16_t on windows - you can change the cvt in the above code to `std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<char32_t>, char32_t> cvt` and have a 32-bit version of the intermediate data... But I admit - I'm testing it on linux to avoid problems with printing utf-8 on windows console

Comment: Oh, so 2 bytes is sufficient for covering BMP which is what you need for any reasonable practical use. I get it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`std::strlen` indeed considers only one byte characters. To compute the length of a unicode NUL terminated string, one can use [`std::wcslen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/wcslen) instead.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cwchar>
#include <clocale>

int main()
{
    const wchar_t* str = L"爆ぜろリアル！弾けろシナプス！パニッシュメントディス、ワールド！";

    std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf8"));
    std::wcout << "The length of \"" << str << "\" is " << std::wcslen(str) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Can it be done without use of wide characters? I wanted to keep only single byte characters inside data structures (char *, const char *, std::string, etc).

Comment: Unfortunately `wcslen` only counts "number of non-null wide characters that precede the terminating null wide character". That is it counts `shots` just like `strlen` counts `bytes`. And will yield wrong results for symbols taking a pair of surrogates, for example U+1D11E.

Comment: @Chris You could `reinterpret` you buffer to be a `wchar_t*` or build a `wstring` from it and use that to call `wcslen`.

Comment: Suggesting to cast buffer with utf-8 `chars` to `wchar_t*` to pass it to `wcslen` is an epic failure.

Comment: OP is using *multibyte* characters, not *wide* characters.  I think you are missing a code conversion step.